# What is the shell exactly when using Cmder on Windows?

Tags: windows, shell, console, operating-system, terminal-emulator

I've just started using Cmder on Windows 7 and I understand that is a console emulator for Windows which gives a better experience than using cmd. However as I understand it the emulator needs to run a shell in order to communicate the user commands to the OS, so on windows what is the shell here? is CMD the default shell for Windows?

Would appreciate just understanding how these tools are connected.

Comment: Interesting question, but rather off-topic here; perhaps it better fits on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Ah sorry I haven't used super user before, I thought someone on here might know.

Comment: There is nothing special about CMD which is called a shell probably because it had special integration into the kernel before (in older versions of Windows).

Comment: Today, CMD is simply a user mode process which makes syscalls and it uses the same API that any other user mode program can use. It doesn't have any integration into the kernel.

Comment: It still does the same things as before though e.g. deleting files etc, but you're saying it uses an API now instead of having an integration into the kernel? what does cmder use then? is it also an API?

Comment: Probably the system() command to simply send the commands you enter to a real CMD process.

Comment: The CMD process takes its main function's arguments and parses them as commands. The system() c++ command simply starts cmd.exe with some arguments to the main function.